# How to crop an image with a rotated rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an image in the form of a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and a rectangle in the form of 4 points (`Vector2`s which are trivially converted to `PointF`s).

I want to use those points to crop out a section of the image. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8700371/65387) which is pretty close to what I want, but I'm not sure how to get the right matrix out of it.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
protected static Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap src, Vector2[] rect)
{
    var width = (rect[1] - rect[0]).Length;
    var height = (rect[3] - rect[0]).Length;
    var result = new Bitmap(M2.Round(width), M2.Round(height));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        using (Matrix mat = new Matrix())
        {
             // ????
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

How can I get the proper transform matrix out of my rect?

Answer (score 1):

It would be the same as in the linked answer, but instead of:

```
mat.Translate(-rect.Location.X, -rect.Location.Y);
mat.RotateAt(angle, rect.Location);
```

You would use:

```
double angle = Math.Atan2(rect[1].Y - rect[0].Y, rect[1].X - rect[0].X);
mat.Translate(-rect[0].X, -rect[0].Y);
mat.RotateAt((float)angle, rect[0]);
```

(Or something along those lines. It may be `-angle`, or `rect[0]` instead of `rect[1]` and vice-versa in `Atan2`. I can’t check immediately…)

Comment: I came up with something quite similar, but it's a little bit off.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
protected static Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap src, Vector2[] rect)
{
    var width = (rect[1] - rect[0]).Length;
    var height = (rect[3] - rect[0]).Length;
    var result = new Bitmap(M2.Round(width), M2.Round(height));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        using (Matrix mat = new Matrix())
        {
            var rot = -Math.Atan2(rect[1].Y - rect[0].Y, rect[1].X - rect[0].X) * M2.RadToDeg;

            mat.Translate(-rect[0].X, -rect[0].Y);
            mat.RotateAt((float)rot, rect[0].ToPointF());

            g.Transform = mat;
            g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```