# Get rotated part of image and align it

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I get part of large image as shown below. Also I have a rotated rectangular region (blue outline). I know the angle of rotation and a corner the outline is rotated about.
Can't figure out how to get a part of this small image within this outline and make it horizontal.

[image]

Comment: [Matrix.RotateAt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.rotateat)

Comment: I know about affine transformations. Simple rotation crops image and translate it:

Comment: You need to change the frame of reference. The rectangle needs to be horizontal and the image rotated. You can then draw the image inside the rectangle. Assuming that you want a new `Image`, create a `Bitmap` of the appropriate dimensions, create a `Graphics` object, translate it and rotate it appropriately, then draw the original `Image`. Spend some time working out the logic by doing it by hand, then write your code to explicitly implement that logic. Don't try to go from a vague idea straight to code.

Comment: You may think it's clear what kind of result you need. 1) *I get part of large image [...]*: is this relevant? Do you have a large image or just a section of it? 2) What is that you want to *rotate*? Just what's inside the already rotated rectangle? Align the entire large image to the rectangle, just a small piece of it? I.e., a small piece of the whole thing (which is still one large object after) or just a separated small piece? 3) *I know the angle of rotation and a corner the outline [...]*: then you can get the center of the rectangle and rotate at the center, hence no translation. etc.

Comment: Try to as explicit as possible when describing what objects you're working with, what tools you can use and what result you want to achieve. Post the code you have tried so far, to give context to this operation; it would also clarify both what objects and tools you have. -- It's also not clear why the question is tagged `winforms`, since there's nothing related to this GUI platform in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a solution. I adapted a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711083/how-to-crop-an-image-with-a-rotated-rectangle) because I need to rotate around different corners of rectangle. The tricky thing is that dpi in my image is different from dpi of display. Here is my solution. This solution uses System.Drawing namespace to work with images

````
    enum RotationCorner
    { TopLeft, BottomLeft, TopRight, BottomRight}

    /// <summary>
    ///   Crop rotated part of source image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">A source image.</param>
    /// <param name="rect">Rectangle area to crop from source image.</param>
    /// <param name="angle">Angle of rotation.</param>
    /// <param name="corner">Corner of rectrangle to rotate about.</param>
    /// <param name="HighQuality">Whether to use <see cref="SmoothingMode"/></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static Image CropRotatedRect(Image source, RectangleF rect, float angle, RotationCorner corner, bool HighQuality)
    {
        var result = new Bitmap((int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height);
        result.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution);
        var x = rect.X;
        var y = rect.Y;
        var dx = 0f;
        var dy = 0f;
        switch (corner)
        {
            case RotationCorner.TopLeft:
            default:
                break;
            case RotationCorner.BottomLeft:
                y = rect.Bottom;
                dy = rect.Height;
                break;
            case RotationCorner.TopRight:
                x = rect.Right;
                dx = rect.Width;
                break;
            case RotationCorner.BottomRight:
                x = rect.Right;
                y = rect.Bottom;
                dx = rect.Width;
                dy = rect.Height;
                break;
        }

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = HighQuality ? InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic : InterpolationMode.Default;
            using (Matrix m = new Matrix())
            {
                m.Translate(-x + dx, -y + dy);
                m.RotateAt(-angle, new PointF(x, y));
                g.Transform = m;
                g.DrawImage(source, new Point(0, 0));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }```
````