# Graphics.DrawPolygon not drawing at correct location

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

On the left is the polygon I drew using my paint-like program. On the right is the polygon drawn by System.Drawing.Bitmap/Graphics:

[image]

The code to draw it is as follows:

```
protected static Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap src, Vector2[] rect)
{
    var result = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        var pen = new Pen(Color.White);

        g.DrawImage(src, new Point(0,0));
        var poly = rect.Select(p => p.ToPointF()).ToArray();
        g.DrawPolygon(pen, poly);

    }
    return result;
}
```

`poly` is:

```
{System.Drawing.PointF[4]}
    [0]: {X = 57.4230042 Y = 57.4229736}
    [1]: {X = 147.058868 Y = 56.0224}
    [2]: {X = 148.43277 Y = 143.951767}
    [3]: {X = 58.7969131 Y = 145.352341}
```

Each of the black squares in the image is 50x50. If you look at `poly`, all the coordinates are exactly as you'd expect: `poly[0]` is a little above 50,50 which corresponds to *inside* the black square labelled "6" (as shown in left image).

So how is `Graphics` getting confused and putting it in the wrong spot? It looks like it's scaling the whole rect down.

Comment: Are you sure the numbers are correct? If the top left of square 1 is (0,0) then the top left of square 6 is (50,50) - so a square one pixel inside square 6 would be (51,51,99,99). Also, you aren't very clear about what is wrong with the result, I'm just assuming that you are trying to draw a border just inside square 6.

Comment: @Jasmine: The left one is the one I drew, I want to the right one to come out exactly the same. i.e., the rect should cover most of squares 6 and 11. You are correct about the coordinates of square 6, it should be (51,51)-(100,100).

Comment: OK that wasn't really clear from the question. Always be explicit about what you are getting and why it is wrong. You got your answer though, I forgot about the scaling in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused. The rectangle is correct, but the background image is scaled up. Note that the 6 and the black square are a lot bigger, but the rectangle is the exact same size.

Note that the [`Graphics.DrawImage` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1.aspx) scales the source image to match the destination resolution.

> This method draws an image using its physical size, so the image will have its correct size in inches regardless of the resolution (dots per inch) of the display device. For example, suppose an image has a pixel width of 216 and a horizontal resolution of 72 dots per inch. If you call this method to draw that image on a device that has a resolution of 96 dots per inch, the pixel width of the rendered image will be (216/72)*96 = 288.

You should use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40.aspx) that accepts a `Rectangle` instead:

```
g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height));
```

Comment: Yes...now that I look more closely, it does appear to be scaling. But that's the entirety of the code; outside I just call `result.Save("crop.jpg")`, so where's the scaling happening?

Comment: Oh... *that's* what it meant by "physical" size?? That was completely unexpected. Thank you!!